# Sum of values in a column basis a condition using SQL

Tags: sql

I want to write a SQL for adding the values in a column (say B) for only those rows where column (say A) has unique value.

| Column A | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Amber | 78 |
| Yellow | 101 |
| Green | 46 |
| Blue | 27 |
| Amber | 78 |
| Yellow | 101 |

So, I want to first select all rows in Column A with unique values (amber, yellow, green and blue) and add there corresponding values from column B. In the above example the answer should be Sum of Column B = 78+101+46+27

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem are you having with your existing attempt? Have you research how to work with *distinct* rows?

Answer (score 0):

But "rows where column (say A) has unique value." are Green and Blue?
In this case the query is:

```
with mytable as (
                 select 'Amber'  as columnA, 78  as columnB from dual union all
                 select 'Yellow' as columnA, 101 as columnB from dual union all
                 select 'Green'  as columnA, 46  as columnB from dual union all
                 select 'Blue'   as columnA, 27  as columnB from dual union all
                 select 'Amber'  as columnA, 78  as columnB from dual union all
                 select 'Yellow' as columnA, 101 as columnB from dual
                )
         select columnA, sum(columnB)
           from mytable
          group by columnA
         having count(*) = 1;    --1 occurrence
```

Otherwise please specify better the key of unique row.

Thank you.